# How to check status without loop and not have application freeze

Tags: javascript

I am not a javascript coder, but was trying to figure out a solution with using HTML Web Forms and Javascript... However, I am using a while loop to keep checking the status of a submitted job, but  because I am doing this, the page freezes. Is there way to check the status without having the page freeze?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><span style="background-color:{color}; border-radius:3px; color:#ffffff; float:right; font-size:16px; padding:2px 4px 2px 4px"><a id='downLoad' href="" download='file' style='display:none' target='_blank'>Save file As</a></span><span style="font-size:24px"><span style="color:#d52b40">Print Survey Report&nbsp;</span></span></p>
<p>Enter the project <b>Print ID</b> and <b>File Name</b> then submit the report for print. Repot may take a few minutes, but a <b>Save File As link</b> will show when ready for download. Right click and select <b>Save Link As</b></p>
<form id='printSurvey'>
  <input type="hidden" id="portalUrl" name="portalUrl" value="https://transportation.bd.esri.com/portal">
  <input type="hidden" id="templateItemId" name="templateItemId" value="a19dc0354ade4e9da65086453d89aa4a">
  <input type="hidden" id="surveyItemId" name="surveyItemId" value="901946f3a7f940f4bab7bbda9d7595e3">
  <input type="hidden" id="featureLayerUrl" name="featureLayerUrl" value="https://transportation-rh.bd.esri.com/server/rest/services/Geotech/GeotechProjectInfoPointSDE/FeatureServer/2">
  <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="toekn was removed">
  <input type="hidden" id="outputFormat" name="outputFormat" value="docx">
  
  <input type="hidden" id="uploadInfo" name="uploadInfo[type]" value="arcgis">
  <input type="hidden" id="uploadInfo" name="uploadInfo[parameters][folderId]" value="6128cd36706f40ddaaa387e9296032a9">
  <input type="hidden" id="uploadInfo" name="uploadInfo[parameters][conflictBehavior]" value="rename"> 
  
  
  <label for="queryParameters">Print ID:</label>
  <input type="text" id="queryParameters" name="queryParameters[objectIds]" placeholder="i.e 1"><br><br>
  
  <label for="outputReportName">Report Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="outputReportName" name="outputReportName" placeholder="Logging Report Name"><br><br>

  <input type="hidden" id="outputPackageName" name="outputPackageName" >
  
  <input type="submit" type="buton" value="Submit">
   
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("outputReportName").addEventListener('focusout',function () { 
    document.getElementById("outputPackageName").value = this.value;
});   
const downLoadTag = document.getElementById('downLoad');


function httpGet(url){
    let xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = url +'?portalUrl=https://transportation.bd.esri.com/portal&token=token was removedenter code here'
    xmlHttpReq.open("GET", url, false); 
    xmlHttpReq.send(null);
    return JSON.parse(xmlHttpReq.responseText);
}



        
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  function sendData() {
    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Bind the FormData object and the form element
    const FD = new FormData(form);

    // Define what happens on successful data submission
    setTimeout(XHR.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
      //alert(event.target.responseText['jobId']);
      var responseArray = JSON.parse(event.target.responseText);
      var jobID = responseArray['jobId'];
      var urlPath = 'https://survey123.arcgis.com/api/featureReport/jobs/'+jobID
      var status = 'esriJobExecuting'
      alert('Report is being generated... This may take several minutes');
      var countEnd = 0
      while (status != 'esriJobSucceeded') {
        var getRep = httpGet(urlPath)
        if (getRep['jobStatus'] == 'esriJobSucceeded'){
            var itemID = getRep['resultInfo']['resultFiles'][0]['id'];
            var urlBeg = 'https://transportation.bd.esri.com/portal/sharing/rest/content/items/';
            var urlEnd = '/data?token=token was removed';
            downLoadTag.href = urlBeg +itemID+urlEnd;
            //console.log(getRep['resultInfo']);
            status = getRep['jobStatus'];
            //console.log(getRep);
            alert('Report is ready for download')
        };
      };
      downLoadTag.style='display:show';
      
    }), 5);

    // Define what happens in case of error
    XHR.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
      alert('Oops! Something went wrong.');
    });

    // Set up our request
    XHR.open("POST", 'https://survey123.arcgis.com/api/featureReport/createReport/submitJob');

    // The data sent is what the user provided in the form
    XHR.send(FD);
  };

  // Get the form element
  const form = document.getElementById("printSurvey");

  // Add 'submit' event handler
  form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    sendData();
    
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using **while** loop this way is the thing that freeze your page so you have to replace it.  `setInterval` would a better solution in almost any cases. Also I would recommend you to use `fetch` instead of very outdated `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: You could take the loop out and use a timer instead? This would reduce the number of requests your making (if several minutes is accurate, your going to be doing A LOT of `httpGet`) and make the document usable

Comment: I kind of figured that the while loop was the problem, but I am inexperienced with javascript on what would be used to used. I'll look into bot the setInterval and fetch

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem recently. There is a Web Workers API. It does everything in the background and doesn't block the main thread. It is easy to learn and understand. Just google Web Workers API and you will get it!